# Mysql slave stuck as sql and io show yes

Tags: mysql

help me with the below issue on slave..

```
mysql> show slave status\G
*************************** 1. row ***************************
               Slave_IO_State: Waiting for master to send event
                  Master_Host: isp-db-mysql-1.be.infra
                  Master_User: slave
                  Master_Port: 3306
                Connect_Retry: 60
              Master_Log_File: isp-db-mysql-1.052619
          Read_Master_Log_Pos: 3138691
               Relay_Log_File: isp-db-mysql-1-relay-bin.000002
                Relay_Log_Pos: 32861
        Relay_Master_Log_File: isp-db-mysql-1.052556
             Slave_IO_Running: Yes
            Slave_SQL_Running: Yes
              Replicate_Do_DB:
          Replicate_Ignore_DB:
           Replicate_Do_Table:
       Replicate_Ignore_Table:
      Replicate_Wild_Do_Table:
  Replicate_Wild_Ignore_Table:
                   Last_Errno: 0
                   Last_Error:
                 Skip_Counter: 0
          Exec_Master_Log_Pos: 8109731
              Relay_Log_Space: 6642282995
              Until_Condition: None
               Until_Log_File:
                Until_Log_Pos: 0
           Master_SSL_Allowed: No
           Master_SSL_CA_File:
           Master_SSL_CA_Path:
              Master_SSL_Cert:
            Master_SSL_Cipher:
               Master_SSL_Key:
        Seconds_Behind_Master: 1111111
Master_SSL_Verify_Server_Cert: No
                Last_IO_Errno: 0
                Last_IO_Error:
               Last_SQL_Errno: 0
               Last_SQL_Error:
1 row in set (0.01 sec)
```

relay log position is not moving, and which made the slave lag as shown above..

i tried to pull the binlog i got this error

@ mysqlbinlog unknown variable 'default-character-set=utf8'

in my.cnf binlog mode is mixed

i tried stop slave, start slave..
nothing worked..

need a quick help , its a issue on prod :-(

change master to changed log,pos is the only wrk around for this ?

Comment: you what? please format your code ...

Comment: I have same issue, where no errors, only "warnings" are in the mysql logs, yet it's obvious that we're hung on a statement, as we're still waiting...

Answer (score 0):

Check the mysql log. There should be an error. Any error will stop replication.

You can quickly get around this by telling the replication to ignore errors, but this may lead to in inconsistency replication! CHeck this post: http://www.howtoforge.com/how-to-skip-certain-errors-in-mysql-replication

Comment: hi , thanks for your reply. you are asking to skip the error. But if you have a clear look at the above status slave has not stopped by any error. it got stuck a particular postion and its not moving from tat position both sql and io shown as yes. so wat could be the issue..

Comment: This is MySQL, anything could be the issue. Hence why I asked you to check the mysql log.